# Volume for sound not consistent when calling string from localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, audio, local-storage

I have a function that is behaving in a way that i do not like, and i cannot identify why.   The overall function works fine, and when the volume is changed using the range element somewhere else in the interface, that works too.  But lets say if I set the object in localStorage to "0.6" it will play at the right volume, BUT every so often it behaves as if the volume is "1" or default(i think).  I sent the variable to my console to see what it says and it behaves like there is nothing wrong.  The audio still sometimes gives me default volume even though the console says it's the right number stored in LS.

Here is the JS to the function that fires my biting sound:

```
biteFunc: function () {
        var snd, myAu;

        myAu = localStorage.getItem("Au");
        //the user uses a range input to set this value, works fine
        snd = new Audio("../Audio/bite.wav");
        //the file in the location i want it to be, works fine

        if (!myAu || myAu === "0") {
            return false;
            //if the user sets the sound to "0", the function will not fire
        }
        if (myAu) {
            snd.volume = myAu;
            snd.play();
             /*this works and the console shows that each time the sound is fired,
             the correct volume is there.  But sometimes(especially when tapping
             the button quickly) the volume behaves like its default or "1"
             even though the object console says the right volume
             */
        }
    }
```

-Could my function be firing without reading the volume and spitting out the default volume when that happens?
-I thought it to be a timeline issue so I set the volume inside of the conditional that detects myAu, still nothing.

Comment: Note, `.volume` expects a number, not a string.

Comment: so, would +myAu work? like: snd.volume = +myAu?   that plus operator in front of the variable... if so, post that as an answer(or post something that will work) and i'll accept it. :)

Comment: What is expected result if `myAu` is equal to `"0"`?

Comment: Is `biteFunc` called more than once? What is purpose of creating a new `<audio>` element at each call to `biteFunc`? Are you expecting each change at `localStorage` should change `.volume` of same `<audio>` element created with `new Audio()`? Or are you trying to create a new `<audio>` element at each call to `biteFunc`?

Comment: guest271314, it returns false, no action. Also, on your other question, biteFunc only get's called when the user hits a button that has that eventListener, only once per click.   Is there a better way to call the audio?

Comment: @MrEhawk82, so this means that each time you click that button, you've got a new sound playing, while the previous one is still playing too. For a better way of doing it, just create your Audio node once, set its src once, and then just change its currentTime to 0 and change its volume before playing it in the click handler.

Comment: thanks, that is the direction that i will work on now

Comment: @MrEhawk82 Note, `javascript` at Question could call `.play()` before media has loaded enough data to begin playback. Use `canplay` event attached to `AudioNode` to call `.play()` within the event handler.

Comment: i have never used canplay nor have i even heard of it.  Looking at the MSDN documentation now, and it looks like my middle name is Dunning-Kreuger because i just now realized how little i know about the audio/video APIs for HTML5.... being autodidactic sucks sometimes.